# getString() error Application::onCreate started from BroadcastReceiver for action android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED

Tags: android

I have some very weird Android crash reports like below from small number of devices and it looks like `getString()` in the `Application::onCreate()` failed in some cases when the Application is created via BroadcastReceiver for the Action '`android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED`'. This is not replicable in our local devices.

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.sample.InstallReceiver: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application com.sample.MyApplication: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.res.Resources.getString(int)' on a null object reference
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2713)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:162)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1426)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        (.....)    
Caused by java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.res.Resources.getString(int)' on a null object reference
       at android.content.Context.getString(Context.java:377)
       at com.sample.MyApplication.initFabric(MyApplication.java:212)
       at com.sample.MyApplication.onCreate(MyApplication.java:124)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1012)
       at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:626)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2649)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:162)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1426)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5430)
```

Comment: What context are you using? Is that un your Activity?

Comment: post java code wher did you get that error ?

Comment: Can you give more details in MyApplication.java

Comment: it looks to me like it has to do something with different languages, users phones language might not be english and your app trying to find the string in users specified language folder, which might not exist

Comment: public class MyApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        String consumerKey = getString(R.string.twitter_api_comsumer_key);
        ...
    }
}

Comment: It's not always happen. We recently added new BroadcastReceiver for android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED. The crashes reported only the case the MyApplication is created via the BroadcastReciever's onReceive.

Comment: We just initialise some 3rd party libraries like Twitter, Fabric, etc. inside `MyApplication::onCreate()` block. The crash tells `Caused by java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.res.Resources.getString(int)' on a null object reference` it looks context.getResources() returns null. Anyone have some similar cases?

Comment: I got the same crash when initializing Flurry right after I enabled Proguard.